# Unable to record native app via jmeter for performance testing

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, record

Im unable to record native app for performance testing via jmeter.tried with various apps from playstore.can anyone please guide me with the same

I am able to record the browser app's but unable to do so from the native app side

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to record an application on [Android version 7](https://www.android.com/versions/nougat-7-0/) or higher without amending its [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) like it's described in the [Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Configure-Android-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording) article

If you don't have access to the application sources you will need a [rooted device](https://www.xda-developers.com/root/) or emulator and JMeter's [certificate installed on it](https://httptoolkit.com/blog/android-11-trust-ca-certificates/)